# scale image in drupal 7

Tags: image, drupal-7, scale

I need to scale image in drupal 7. IF the width is greater than the height, THEN scale the image to 200px height. IF the height is greater than the width, THEN scale the image to 200px width. and if the width and height are the same, scale to 200x200. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the admin menu:

```
Configuration->Media->Image styles
```

Create a new style and adjust the effects to suit your needs